# Pixelate image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Thanks to phun-ky, i have manage to stabilize the page. I deleted animation from code. Now i need to find a way to instead of pixilize the whole image when cursor in on the page, to pixelate a point where cursor clicks on the image. Just like photoshops that use Filter › Pixelate › Mosaic. Any solutions or suggestions

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pixelate Image</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      img = new Image();

    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/w1yg6qo.jpg';
    img.onload = function() {
      pixelate();
    };

    function pixelate(v) {

      var size = v ? v * 0.01 : 1,
        w = canvas.width * size,
        h = canvas.height * size;

      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

      ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    }

    function focus(v) {

      var size = v * 0.01,
        w = canvas.width * size,
        h = canvas.height * size;

      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

      ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    }

    function mouseoverHandler() {
      pixelate(5);
    }

    function mouseoutHandler() {
      focus(100);
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach, with the basis of this code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    play = false;

ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/w1yg6qo.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    pixelate();
};

function pixelate(v) {

    var size = v ? v * 0.01 : 1,
        w = canvas.width * size,
        h = canvas.height * size;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

function focus(v) {

    var size = v * 0.01,
        w = canvas.width * size,
        h = canvas.height * size;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

function mouseoverHandler() {

    var v = 100,
        dx = 1.75;

    anim();

    function anim() {

        v -= dx;

        pixelate(v);

        if (v > 5) {
            requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }

    }

}

function mouseoutHandler() {

    var v = 1,
        dx = 2.75;

    anim();

    function anim() {

        v += dx;
        
        if (v > 100) {
            v = 100;
        }

        focus(v);

        if (v < 100) {
            requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }

    }

}

canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseoutHandler, false);

window.requestAnimationFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Pseudocode:

1. Put two canvases with the image on top of each other
2. the overlay canvas is a circle with a border radius that has a transparent border
3. check mousex/mousey on the event and map out the coordinates to move the position of the canvas to fit the position of the click event on the first canvas
4. add the desired pixelation feature

Comment: Thanks bro, but maybe you know how to resolve problem with it now?

Comment: I've gave you all the building blocks that you need to do it. I am not working for you, and if I did, you would learn nothing :)